# Mysql - insert N'...'

Tags: mysql

This is a small mysql question, but I recently found a query that I don't understand while reading a SO question.

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("insert into users (username,pass,fname,lname,phone,city) VALUES (N'$email',N'$pass',N'$fname',N'$lname',N'$phone',N'$city')");
```

What do the N'...' means is the insert query?
Does this is required when dealing with UTF8?

If I had to write the same query, I would have written:

```
mysql_query("insert into users (username,pass,fname,lname,phone,city) VALUES ('$email','$pass','$fname','$lname','$phone','$city')");
```

What is the differences between the two?

Comment: It's explained in the documentation. It's called ["National Character Set"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-national.html)

Answer (score 1):

[NVarchar](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/nvarchar_n) is the data type used for Unicode. If your database is not storing multilingual Data then you can keep using Varchar. As an example: N'abc' (as in your case) simply converts your string to unicode.

By default SQL server uses the Windows-1252 character codes for varchar. It contains most of characters for latin-based languages (English, German, French, etc.) But it does not contain characters for non-latin based languages (Polish, Russian, etc.). As stated above, nvarchar is used to get around that issue because it is for Unicode which contains those missing characters. This comes at a cost, it takes twice as much space to store nvarchar than varchar.

Putting N in front of your string ensures the characters are converted to Unicode before being placed into a nvarchar column. Most of the time you will be okay leaving the N off, but I wouldn't recommend it. It is a lot better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks, but do the `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` change the way mysql handle the varchar / nvarchar stuff?

Comment: Yeah.. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) out....